# countif in macros gives 0 results

Tags: excel, vba, countif, visual-studio-macros

​I was trying to do a countif in a column B named First Name that has different names in it but the results is returning 0.

Here is my code:

Public Sub counting()
    Dim lastcell As String

```
Range("B2").Select

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lastcell = ActiveCell.Address

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "=countif(B2:" + lastcell + ", John)"

End Sub
```

If I check the formula written in the active cell it is:

=COUNTIF(B2:$B$16, John)

Please help.

I tried changing the line from

ActiveCell.Value = "=countif(B2:" + lastcell + ", John)"

to

ActiveCell.Value = "=countif(B2:" + lastcell + ", "John")" still not working.

Comment: that is not `countif in a macro`. you are using a macro to place a formula into a cell (same as if you have typed it in).  check the resulting formula in the worksheet cell to see if it is correct and make corrections to your code if it is not correct ..... note: do not use `select ... activecell` ... use `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=countif(B2:" + lastcell + ", John)"`

Comment: Thank you jstola, but the result is still 0.

Comment: what is the formula in cell below lastcell ?

Comment: use `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "=countif(B2:" + lastcell + ", ""John"")"`

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!! it works now!

Comment: makes no sense why that worked and Tim's code did not

Comment: Will I able to loop on that too? For example, it will count the number of "John", "Mark", "Mike" and highlight the row of that name (in any color) if it's more than 50% of the total count.
Let's say there are 10 entries and there are 5 or more "John" in that column.

Thank you so much for the help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub counting()
    With Range("B2").End(xlDown)
        .Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=COUNTIF(B2:" & .Address(False, False) & ", ""John"")"
    End with
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my query.
I tried your code (copy+paste) and it is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: that should have worked ... are any of the lines colored red in the editor?  ... do you have any data in column B ?

Comment: Works for me.  It will fail if there's no content in B3 though.

Comment: Hi Tim, oh sorry need to inform you that it's in a table style  medium 2( blue and white. Thank you Tim.

Comment: makes no difference what color the cells are

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
ActiveCell.formula = "=countif(B2:" & lastcell & chr(44) & chr(34) &"John" &chr(34) & ")"
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped,
Thank you for answering my query. It is returning a 0 as a results.